# How to display multiple colors in a lineseries?

Tags: apache-flex, colors, lineseries

I want to display different colors in a line series based on some condition. As per my observation we can use fillFunction on columnseries to get different colored chart items, but it does not have any effect on lineseries. Is there any way by which we can get multi colored line series?

Answer (score 0):

Can it help you?

[flex line chart with variable colored line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528652/flex-line-chart-with-variable-colored-line)

The approach is a little bit strange but it works by me.